# DropDownList setting selected item in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I set the default value for the DrowDownList?

I have something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BusinessID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Businesses, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**EDIT:**

```
    // GET: Reviews/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Businesses = new SelectList(db.Businesses, "BusinessID", "BusinessName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReviewID,ReviewText,Rating,BusinessID")] Review review, int id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reviews.Add(review);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Businesses", new { id = review.BusinessID });
        }

        review.BusinessID = id;
        ViewBag.Businesses = new SelectList(db.Businesses, "BusinessID", "BusinessName", review.BusinessID);
        return View(review);
    }
```

How I call it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Write a review", "Create", "Reviews", new { id = Model.BusinessID }, null)
```

And the point is that each my BusinessID, has a value, and I call them let's say like this /Reviews/Create/15, so in this case BusinessID is 15. And when the page loads, I want the item with the BusinessID 15 to be selected by default. But whenever I load the page, it always selects the one with the lowest BusinessID.

**UPDATE:**

Changing GET action to this solved the problem:

```
        public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.Businesses = new SelectList(db.Businesses, "BusinessID", "BusinessName", id);
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Is `BusinessID` part of the model for the view?

Comment: @DavidTansey yes, and I want to give a specific selected value, using the BusinessID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be using the strongly typed versions, it makes this much easier, and less error prone.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BusinessID, Model.Businesses, new { @class="form-control" })
```

here. Model.Businesses is an IEnuerable (which can be a List, Collection, array, etc..)

Or you can use ViewBag, like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BusinessID, ViewBag.Businesses, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Now, i'm unclear on what you mean by "default value" here.  Do you mean you want to set the value to a value that is in your database?  In which case, you simply populate your model.BusinessID with the value you want it to be set to (make sure it's the value, not the text) and it will automatically select it when it renders the page.

If you mean you want something like "Select a Business..." then you would use the "option" overload:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BusinessID, ViewBag.Businesses, "Select a Business...", new {@class="form-control" })
```

Note: Do NOT name your list of SelectListItems (or your SelectList) the same as your Selected item property, ie.. do not do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BusinessID, ViewBag.BusinessID, "Select a Business...", new {@class="form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but it's still a bit unclear to me, and I guess to you also. Check my update.

Comment: @ett - I was unclear about what you meant by "default value", since it could mean two things.  Based on your update, you want to use my second example, but pay close attention to the last sentence in my answer, particularly when using a SelectList.

Comment: I still don't know what I need to change. I understood that they shouldn't be same name. But, I don't know what I should change exactly. Can you write exactly, how my DropDownList should look?

Comment: @ett - I did that.  I repeat.  You can use my second example.  Use it exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: If I write the second example, with the Viewbag, exactly as it is, I get the following error message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ComputerBigPlayer.Models.Review>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: My apologies, you need to cast the `ViewBag.Businesses`, to `(SelectList)ViewBag.Businesses`  This is because you can't pass a dynamic type to an expression, which strongly typed helpers are, so you have to tell it what the type is.

Comment: Yes, this compiled, but I still have the same result as before. The one with the lowest BusinessID, is always selected automatically. No matter, whether I call it as Reviews/Create/16, or Reviews/Create/15, or whatever. I posted the whole method, maybe it helps.

Comment: @ett - that's because you're still using ViewBag.BusinessID, even though I said not to numerous times.

Comment: Even, if I comment that line out, it still doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @ett - if you comment that line out, it can't work at all.. you don't have anything to populate the dropdown list with.  It should e called Viewbag.Businesses, not Viewbag.BusinessID.

Comment: It also works if I comment that line out, and when I change it to ViewBag.Businesses, it also works, but still not with the desired outcome.

Comment: @ett - Ok, if it still works with it commented out, then we're on a wild goose chase here.  It's not possible.  You aren't populating the dropdown with any lists..  Obviously this is not the actual code that is executing, otherwise you would be getting a null reference exception because there are no lists in the dropdown.

Comment: Okay, check out, I update my question, so you can see how I navigate to Create, and how my other part looks.

Comment: @ett - are you by any chance modifying only the post action, and not the get action?

Comment: Check my code, you can see both my GET and POST actions.

Comment: @ett - The Get action you just added a) doesn't have an id parameter, and b) doesn't pass the (non-existent) id to to view because it's not creating a model.  I really don't understand how this code can be working without throwing exceptions, unless you're actually executing different code.  Have you put breakpoints in these actions to make sure they are the ones that are executing?

Comment: @ett - really?  That's odd, since the selected value field of SelectList isn't used with strongly typed helpers, so without passing a model to the view, I don't see how that worked...

Comment: It works, just fine now. The view already has model, if it is what you are saying. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 2):

When you are passing the Model to the view, set BusinessID property of model.
Use the following code :

```
//Assuming you bind the model to View using Create Action
 public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Businesses = new SelectList(db.Businesses, "BusinessID", "BusinessName");
    var reviewModel = new Review();
    reviewModel.BusinessID = 15;
    return View(reviewModel);
}
```

Main part is setting the value of "BusinessID" property while binding the model to view.